# Can we use different versions of Mercurial/TortoiseHg to work with the same central repository?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Is there a risk of damaging the repository (using a file share) if we use different versions or the tools to pull from and push to the central repository?

*FYI: The central repository was created with Mercurial 1.5. We are planning to upgrade our tools to Mercurial 1.8 with Tortoise 2.0.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're describing is safe to do.  Every version of Mercurial can safely read and write repositories created by older versions.  Older clients will refuse to read/write repositories that are too new for them.

So as long as you're accessing repos created with 1.5 you can do so with 1.8 just great.

More detail: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RequiresFile